# 3 Column review HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at this website (even though I know its a scam) and saw a cool 3 split review column [3 Column Review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yopS9.png) and would like to implement this into my site.
I have looked into it and have not been able to corretly align the text how I want it. Is there a snippet that I could use? If this is too broad I am sorry.

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. If you want others to write full code for you, you should consider hiring a freelancer. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: If you want an easy column system, consider implementing Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Watt Erikson, you could have asked the same question as follows.

How do I create three columns in CSS.

You write your questions like this: It was late at night and I was hungry so I was having some coffee and I was dipping some cookies in my coffee while I looked at this site (although I didn't like the look of the site because the site is yellow and I like purple websites) and I saw a three column review.... blah blah blah.

You probably didn't do much research.
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: Sorry about writing so weirdly. I don't use this site often. Thanks for the help! W3schools is very helpful thanks for that!